# Convert Swift Array to Dictionary with indexes

Tags: swift, functional-programming, swift2, swift3

I'm using Xcode 6.4

I have an array of UIViews and I want to convert to a Dictionary with keys `"v0", "v1"...`. Like so:

```
var dict = [String:UIView]()
for (index, view) in enumerate(views) {
  dict["v\(index)"] = view
}
dict //=> ["v0": <view0>, "v1": <view1> ...]
```

This works, but I'm trying to do this in a more functional style. I guess it bothers me that I have to create the `dict` variable. I would love to use `enumerate()` and `reduce()` like so:

```
reduce(enumerate(views), [String:UIView]()) { dict, enumeration in
  dict["v\(enumeration.index)"] = enumeration.element // <- error here
  return dict
}
```

This feels nicer, but I'm getting the error: `Cannot assign a value of type 'UIView' to a value of type 'UIView?'` I have tried this with objects other an `UIView` (ie: `[String] -> [String:String]`) and I get the same error.

Any suggestions for cleaning this up?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

try like this:

```
reduce(enumerate(a), [String:UIView]()) { (var dict, enumeration) in
    dict["\(enumeration.index)"] = enumeration.element
    return dict
}
```

**Xcode 8 • Swift 2.3**

```
extension Array where Element: AnyObject {
    var indexedDictionary: [String:Element] {
        var result: [String:Element] = [:]
        for (index, element) in enumerate() {
            result[String(index)] = element
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

**Xcode 8 • Swift 3.0**

```
extension Array  {
    var indexedDictionary: [String: Element] {
        var result: [String: Element] = [:]
        enumerated().forEach({ result[String($0.offset)] = $0.element })
        return result
    }
}
```

**Xcode 9 - 10 • Swift 4.0 - 4.2**

Using Swift 4 `reduce(into:)` method:

```
extension Collection  {
    var indexedDictionary: [String: Element] {
        return enumerated().reduce(into: [:]) { $0[String($1.offset)] = $1.element }
    }
}
```

---

Using Swift 4 `Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:)` initializer and passing a new array from the enumerated collection:

```
extension Collection {
    var indexedDictionary: [String: Element] {
        return Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: enumerated().map{(String($0),$1)})
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe this fixes it! Do you have any idea why this works? Most of the documentation I've seen on closures has omitted `var` in the parameters.

Comment: dict is a constant by default. If you would like to change it you need to declare it as variable. :)

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Thank you so much, I've been at this for way too long tonight :)