# How do I create dictionary from array of tuples?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, tuples

Let’s say I have array of objects that can be identified and I want to create dictionary from it. I can easily get tuples from my array like so:

```
let tuples = myArray.map { return ($0.id, $0) }
```

But I can’t see initializer for dictionary to take array of tuples. Am I missing something? Do I have create extension for dictionary for this functionality (in fact it’s not hard but I thought it would be supplied by default) or there is easier way to do that?

There is code for extension

```
extension Dictionary
{
    public init (_ arrayOfTuples : Array<(Key, Value)>)
    {
        self.init(minimumCapacity: arrayOfTuples.count)

        for tuple in arrayOfTuples
        {
            self[tuple.0] = tuple.1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should it be by default? There's no general way to map array of tuples to the Dictionary. In Dictionary each key must be unique, in array of tuples any number of repeating `keys` is allowed. What to do with them? Rewrite? Ignore?

Comment: Yes, @user28434 is right. Btw have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31447400/4272498

Comment: Yeah, You're right @user28434 , I wasn't thinking about that.

Comment: Why are you creating an array of tuples in the first place? You can created the dictionary with the data in myArray directly instead.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

**Swift 4**

If your tuples is (Hashable, String) you can use:

```
let array = [("key1", "value1"), ("key2", "value2"), ("key3", "value3")]
let dictionary = array.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.0] = $1.1 }
print(dictionary) // ["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"]
```

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted as this is the most appropriate approach to solve the question OP asked.

Comment: I  ❤️ this answer!

Comment: This solution does not work by-default. `$0` as accumulative dictionary comes immutable on each iteration of `reduce` function so you need a kind of mutable new value to handle that.

Answer (score 23):

## Swift 4

For creation you can use native Dictionary's **init** functions:

```
Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: [("a", 0), ("b", 1)]) 
// ["b": 1, "a": 0]

Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: [("a", 0), ("b", 1), ("b", 2)])
// Fatal error: Duplicate values for key: 'b'

// takes the first match
Dictionary([("a", 0), ("b", 1), ("a", 2)], uniquingKeysWith: { old, _ in old })
// ["b": 1, "a": 0]

// takes the latest match
Dictionary([("a", 0), ("b", 1), ("a", 2)], uniquingKeysWith: { $1 }) 
// ["b": 1, "a": 2]
```

Also if you want to have the shortcut:

```
Dictionary([("a", 0), ("b", 1), ("a", 2)]) { $1 } 
// ["b": 1, "a": 2]
```

Answer (score 8):

Depending on what you want to do, you could:

```
let tuples = [(0, "0"), (1, "1"), (1, "2")]
var dictionary = [Int: String]()
```

**Option 1: replace existing keys**

```
tuples.forEach {
    dictionary[$0.0] = $0.1
}    
print(dictionary) //prints [0: "0", 1: "2"]
```

**Option 2: Don't allow repeting keys**

```
enum Errors: Error {
    case DuplicatedKeyError
}

do {
    try tuples.forEach {
        guard dictionary.updateValue($0.1, forKey:$0.0) == nil else { throw Errors.DuplicatedKeyError }
    }
    print(dictionary)
} catch {
    print("Error") // prints Error
}
```

Answer (score 6):

#### A generic approach:

```
/**
 * Converts tuples to dict
 */
func dict<K,V>(_ tuples:[(K,V)])->[K:V]{
    var dict:[K:V] = [K:V]()
    tuples.forEach {dict[$0.0] = $0.1}
    return dict
}
```

**Functional programming update:**

```
func dict<K,V>(tuples:[(K,V)])->[K:V]{
    return tuples.reduce([:]) {
       var dict:[K:V] = $0
       dict[$1.0] = $1.1   
       return dict
    }
}
```

Comment: @hasen Thats debatable. Since you pass the tuples as an argument it definitely shouldn't be just func. Making it static explicitly says that it can't change the state of the class it resides in

Comment: It doesn't need to reside in a class. It's just a function. Swift is not Java.

Comment: @hasen I guess it's Opinionated  I'll change it to func for the sake of brevity. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I put this function as a Dictionary extension init.

Comment: @DanielT. There is already a native one: init(uniqueKeysWithValues:)  (swift 4)

Answer (score 3):

Improved @GitSync answer using an extension.

```
extension Array {
    func toDictionary<K,V>() -> [K:V] where Iterator.Element == (K,V) {
        return self.reduce([:]) {
            var dict:[K:V] = $0
            dict[$1.0] = $1.1
            return dict
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update to @Stefan answer's.

```
extension Array {

    func toDictionary<K, V>() -> [K: V] where Iterator.Element == (K, V) {
        return Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: self)
    }
}
```