# Removing from complex custom array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have array of custom objects

```
var shopList = [String: [ShopItem]]()
```

Custom class

```
class ShopItem {
var id = ""
var name = ""
var quantity = 0.0
var price = 0.0
var category = ""


init(id: String, name: String, quantity: Double, price: Double, category: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.quantity = quantity
    self.price = price
    self.category = category
}


var uom: String {

    return "шт."
}

var total: Double {
    return quantity * price
}
```

}

What is right way to remove object from array? 
I tried to do it way below

[image]

```
extension ShopItem: Equatable {}
func ==(left: ShopItem, right: ShopItem) -> Bool {
return left.id == right.id
}
```

But as you see I got error :(

Comment: just use enumerated() method and change your array element with the element offset

Comment: could you give example, please :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31447400/2303865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to value semantics (objects are copied rather than referenced) the `value` object is immutable. Even if you assign `value` to a variable the object is not removed in the `shopList` dictionary.

You need to remove the object directly in the dictionary (the code is Swift 3)

```
func removeItem(item: ShopItem) {
    for (key, value) in shopList {
        if let index = value.index(of: item) {
            shopList[key]!.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```