# Enumerating dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, enumeration

I guess I noticed a bug in the Swift Dictionary enumeration implementation.

The output of this code snippet:

```
var someDict:[Int:String] = [1:"One", 2:"Two", 3:"Three"]
for (key, value) in someDict.enumerated() {
   print("Dictionary key \(key) - Dictionary value \(value)")
}
```

should be:

```
Dictionary key 2 - Dictionary value Two
Dictionary key 3 - Dictionary value Three
Dictionary key 1 - Dictionary value One
```

instead of:

```
Dictionary key 0 - Dictionary value (key: 2, value: "Two")
Dictionary key 1 - Dictionary value (key: 3, value: "Three")
Dictionary key 2 - Dictionary value (key: 1, value: "One")
```

Can anyone please explain this behavior?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31447400/2303865

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's **not** a bug, you are causing the confusion because you are using the wrong API.

You get your expected result with this (***dictionary related***) syntax

```
for (key, value) in someDict { ...
```

where

- `key` is the dictionary key
- `value` is the dictionary value.

---

Using the (***array related***) syntax

```
for (key, value) in someDict.enumerated() { ...
```

which is actually

```
for (index, element) in someDict.enumerated() { ...
```

the dictionary is treated as an array of tuples and

- `key` is the **index**
- `value` is a **tuple** `("key": <dictionary key>, "value": <dictionary value>)`